# change the layout for wordpress post listings

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

On my WordPress posts listings page, i.e. the page which lists all the posts with excerpts from each one, I'd like to change the format & structure of the post listings so that it shows the date , title, author, tags excerpt and read more link in that order for each post listing. I would also like to add some of my own static text in the listing & remove some of the features that came with my theme.

I've tried changing the `single.php file` in my child theme but this hasn't had any effect? Maybe I'm changing the wrong part of it or am working on the wrong file?

How do I add tags to the post listings is it something similar to `<?php the_title(); ?>`?

How do I format the date?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where do you want to show the things, in which page you want the things to be visible?

Comment: on the blog listings page i.e. the page which lists all the blog posts with excerpts from each post

Comment: Then, you are dealing with `index.php` or `front-page.php`. But some themes like Twenty Twelve the post formats are separated into a different file called `contents.php` etc. You have to edit there.

Comment: To be able to give an accurate answer, you should provide information about the theme you're using. `single.php` is probably not the place to look. As @MayeenulIslam mentions, `index.php` is a good place to look, but it may also be `category.php`, `archive.php` or another template file. Many of these delegate to smaller files that generate output for each specific post. These tend to have names like `content-post.php`.

Comment: We're using the jupiter theme

Comment: Generally single.php is used for rendering pages with full post content. SirReal gave a good advance to look up in different files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to edit the main blog page, this is the `home.php` file in most templates, for more information on which file to edit see [this visual template overview](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Visual_Overview). You can see here that if `home.php` is not found in the theme, WordPress will use index.php to show the posts instead

All of your other questions can be easily answered by saerching the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/):

- [Formatting date and time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time)
- [Displaying the tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a template if you do not want to mess up theme's core files.

Create a Template: Posts Listing
Add a page in wordpress backend and selected the above created template.

Code for all posts listing:
    /* Query for Fetching all Blog Posts */
    $myposts = query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=3&order=DESC');
    foreach( $myposts as $post ){
    setup_postdata($post);

// Prints title
     // Prints thumbnail
    
    
     
    
    
    
    
     '
    ' . __( 'Pages:',      'hawkamah' ) .  '', 'after' => '' ) ); ?>

Comment: If you add a template to an existing theme this file will still be removed when updating the theme. Using a child theme (like the OP is doing) is the way to go, that's the proper way of overwriting a WordPress theme.